# Angular Test: ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am trying to run `ng test` and receiving this error. How can I fix this? Not even sure what it means.

> ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active07 01 2020 21:25:31.477:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9877/
07 01 2020 21:25:31.537:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
07 01 2020 21:25:31.538:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
07 01 2020 21:25:31.551:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.
07 01 2020 21:25:54.710:INFO [Chrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket with id 
Chrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.008 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.008 secs / 0 secs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the source file(test.ts file in this case) is missing from the path you mentioned in the angular.json.

Recheck the path of test.ts mentioned in the angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

checkout your angular.json file and look into paths of build and test objects
like

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
          }
        },
```

If this does not work then share your code

Answer (score 0):

You could try a complete reinstall of *node modules* - it worked for me.

`npm ci`